Problem getting the value from a cell using M in excel
I have a series of reports written in Excel. In these reports, there is an specific sheet called "My_Sheet" where in the position G3 there is a number.
I am constructing global report (also written in excel) in which I have the number associated to each report as a column.
I have used Code_Copilot to generate a function since I am no expert on M language.
`let
    // Load the files from the folder
    Origen = Folder.Files("C:\Users\J\MyFolder"),

// Filter hidden files
#"Filter hidden attributes" = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),

// Add a function to extract G3
#"Invocar función para extraer G3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filter hidden attributes", "G3 Value", each 
    let
        // Load the content of the Excel file
        Source = Excel.Workbook([Content], true), // Open the file
        // Select the sheet that contains the specific table
        MySheet_Sheet = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "My_Sheet")), 
        
        // Check if the sheet exists
        G3_Value = if Table.RowCount(MySheet_Sheet) > 0 then
            let
                // Get the content of the sheet
                SheetContent = MySheet_Sheet{0}[Content],
                // Extract the value from cell G3 (third row, seventh column)
                ValueG3 = try SheetContent{2}[Column7] otherwise "No data"
            in
                ValueG3
        else
            "Sheet not found" // If the sheet doesn't exist
    in
        G3_Value
),

// Select only the columns with the file name and G3 value
#"Select final columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invocar función para extraer G3", {"Name", "G3 Value"})
in
    #"Select final columns"
`

This, however, returns that no data is detected.

The data looks like this, that is the My_Sheet

Thus, a value of 3 should be expected at least in the first image in the row associated to the second screenshot.
Any answer is appreciated.
Best regards.

The column in MySheet_Sheet is actually called Data not Content, and it seems to automatically promote headers in my tests so you actually want row 2 of the resulting table:
            SheetContent = MySheet_Sheet{0}[Data],
            // Extract the value from cell G3 (second row, seventh column due to first row promotion)
            ValueG3 = try SheetContent{1}[Column7] otherwise "No data"


If there's nothing in Column A, then it will be in the sixth column. And, in my testing, trying to mimic the structure he showed, it was initially in the fourth row (before the promote headers step).

@RonRosenfeld I must admit PQ seems like the wrong option to me for something like this.

Thanks for the answer, however, I get No data as a result

@slow_learner Looking at your picture, I suspect the column is not called Column7 as  you have data in G1. Is that data always the same? Also, do you actually have to use Power Query for this?

@Rory Yep, that was it. I tought that the name change only occured if a table was defined. Thank you

I suggest you create a Defined Name for that cell. eg Formulas => Define Name => Define Name. I named that cell _G3.
Then you can use code like this to access it:
= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Full_Path), null, true){[Item="_G3", Kind="DefinedName"]}[Data]

If you are going to be reading in all the files in a folder, and then extracting the value of _G3 from each file that contains that, putting that value in an additional column, you can use:
let

//Read in all the files in the folder
//Note: Folder.Files includes subfolders
//     Folder.Contents does not
    Source = Folder.Contents(folderPath),

//Filter to just return the .xlsx files
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Extension] = ".xlsx" and not [Attributes][Hidden]),


//Return G3 Value or null if there is no named range
    #"Add G3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Valor G3",
        each try Excel.Workbook(
                    File.Contents([Folder Path] & [Name]))
                        {[Name="_G3", Kind="DefinedName"]}[Data][Column1]{0} otherwise "sin datos")
in
    #"Add G3"

You could access it by sheet / row / column if you can be confident that the structure of the worksheet will always be the same. But the problem is that the location of the cell in the data downloaded by power BI is dependent on the worksheet structure.
For example, if there is nothing in Column A, then G3 will be in the sixth column. If you use a Defined Name, you don't have to worry about the sheet structure (or even the sheet name).

Thanks for the answer. However, I have a doubt, in File.Contents(Full_Path) I have put the folder path C:\Users\J\MyFolder. However, I am getting the following error Expression.Error: The path 'C:\Users\J\MyFolder' is a folder path. A file path is expected. I cannot write the name of the file (AAA.xlsx) since the goal is to dump docens of files in the folder and have them sumarized using the expression for "Valor G3"

@slow_learner See my amended Answer.

Using defined name seems to be the safest option - it is good know that PQ omits empty columns and there's no option to control it.
